# Trying to fill a zeros numpy array of size (6,6) with a array size (2,2)

Tags: resize, numpy-ndarray, fill

I have a array S:

```
S = array([[980, 100],
          [  3,   5]])
```

I need to resize him or fill a zeros array to size (6,6). My desire output is:

```
out = array([[980, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

## Create a zeros matrix to desired size matrix

zeros = np.zeros((6,6))

## your array

array = np.array([[1,2,5,6],[3,4,4,3],[5,6,2,8]])

#getting shape
lenx, leny = array.shape

## fill the zeros matrix with your array

zeros[:lenx,:leny] = array